# How to reassign a shortcut key?

Tags: windows, shortcuts

Previously, Ctrl + D was assigned to an application by a shortcut on the desktop.  The shortcut is now deleted but shortcut key is still assigned to the same application.

How can I reassign Ctrl + D to a new application?

Comment: Is this programming related?

Comment: Not as far as I can tell.

Comment: Close close close :)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.windowsbbs.com/windows-xp/46822-shortcut-key.html This might help!

Comment: this didn't help me much. :(

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for this.  It's weird, and I don't understand it, but it works.  Here are the steps: 1) Create a new user account.  2) Log in to the new account.  3) Log out from the new account.  4) When you go back to the original account, you should be able to re-use the shortcut key.  You can now delete the new account.  Like I said, weird.

Answer (score 0):

In a similar situation (key assigned to a deleted shortcut that was still active), I restarted the Explorer process, and got my key back. (On Windows XP.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) to remap hotkeys with its scripting language.